# Global ssh key on server to be used for all accounts

Tags: ssh, webserver, ssh-keys

I work for a web development company that also manages the hosting of our customers websites.The hosting is shared and only on 3 servers. The webservers are Debian webservers where each customer has his own account to reach his own website files.

Normally I would log in to the server as this customer and add my ssh key to an authorized_keys file so that I can simply ssh into the account without having to lookup the password, this works perfectly fine.

The downside is I have to do this for every account over again, is there a way to add it to the server only once so that I can access all the accounts?

I tried putting the authorized_keys file in a .ssh folder in the root of the server but this doesn't seem to provide me access with any account. I have to admit my Linux knowledge is limited, so am wondering if this is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also asnwered original post on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836829/global-ssh-key-on-server)

You can update your `sshd_config` and add to `AuthorizedKeysFile` also for example some path in `/etc/ssh/authorized_keys` where you can put your master key. This would authorize you with this key to all accounts. But don't forget to leave there also the original one:

```
[...]
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys /etc/ssh/authorized_keys
[...]
```

Or you can use certificates as described in `ssh-keygen` manual page. This would allow you to audit the access with these keys.

Answer (score 3):

This question has been answered on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/434896)

The place to set this up is in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`